# Trying to add event listener so that when any form field is empty, it displays "Please enter a value"

Tags: javascript, this

Although it works when I remove addEventListener and add onblur="validateNonEmpty(this.form);" in each input element. Also it would be great if I can get to know difference between passing 'this' and 'this.form'. Any article explaining different scenarios to use 'this' keyword would be great!

```
<body>
 <form action="">
        Enter the banner message: <input type="text" name="message" id="message" value=""><span
            class="helpText"></span><br>
        Enter ZIP code of the location: <input type="text" name="ZIP" id="ZIP" value=""><span
            class="helpText"></span><br>
        Enter the date for the message to be shown: <input type="text" name="date" id="date" value=""><span
            class="helpText"></span><br>
        Enter your name: <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value=""><span class="helpText"></span><br>
        Enter your phone number: <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value=""><span class="helpText"></span><br>
        Enter your email address: <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value=""><span class="helpText"></span>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Order Banner">
    </form>
</body>
```

```
 <script>
        let z = document.querySelectorAll('input');
        for (let i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
            z[i].addEventListener('onblur', validateNonEmpty(this.form));
        }

        function validateNonEmpty(inputField) {
            if (inputField.value.length == 0) {
                document.querySelector('.helpText').innerHTML = "please enter a value";
                return false;
            } else {
                document.querySelector('.helpText').innerHTML = "";
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: why don't you use the placeholder attribute?

Comment: How it is gonna help in "validateNonEmpty" function run correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the next time try to make a question more clear.

The difference between **"this"** and **"this.form"** is that the first is the input and the second is the form that the input belongs. I supposed you are a little confused about **this**. When you attach a function to an event, the this variable that is passed to the function refer to the element that trigger the event, in this case always is an input element, but the input elements also have a form property, you aren't getting the global forms variable, is the form of the input.

In [Javascript.info](https://javascript.info/object-methods) you can get a better overview about what is happening.

Comment: That makes sense, the issue I am facing is the above code gives an error if I pass only "this" in the argument as well. It says 'cant get the value of undefined'. Whereas it works when I remove addEventListener and include onblur="validateNonEmpty(this);" in each input tag.